# SharePoint 2010 Alternate Access Mappings Always Resolve To Port 80

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, alternate-access-mapping, dns, port

In SharePoint 2010 environment I have some of my web applications running on different ports e.g. `http://my-sharepoint-server:12345`

In the AAM settings in Central Administration I have the default zone AAM set to `http://my-sharepoint-server:12345` and the intranet zone set to `http://myapp.mydomain.net`

But the `myapp.mydomain.net` always resolves to port `80` and not to port `12345`.

How do I make the AAM URL resolve to port `12345`?

Comment: Have you checked your IIS configurations for the site? Open IIS, select your site assigned for `myapp.mydomain.net` and from right-hand-side open Bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Central Administration----Apps-----Configure app url ----- Enter the new url in form myapp.mydomain.net:12345

Another way is using ISS bindings which is more complicated.

Comment: Doing this would mean that the port number would have to be visible to end-users in the URL.  This would defeat some of the purpose of the 'friendly' URL provided by AAM.

Comment: IF you are looking for a friendly URL apps URL is not the right place to look for here is the url of an app in sharepoint : 
https://app-f718e3efc340f8.apps.mycompany.de
Unless your users have a photographic memory they are not going to remember it and adding the port number won't make the domain worse than it already is. moreover you can not change extension before the app URL. 
You are welcome btw.

Comment: This is for SharePoint 2010 I'm asking ... I just used the "myapp" in my example URL.  The URL could be http : // somesite.yourdomain.net  When I add an Alternate Access Mapping in Central Admin for a web app it resolves to port 80 even though the default site runs on another port.  If I want the AAM to resolve to the same port as the default zone AAM I have to put the port number into the URL.